# Configuring DVWA on nginx using docker

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-config

run nginx o ndocker and host DVW on nginx

To demonstrate what I did. I installed docker -> pull the nginx image -> port biding 8000:80 to access nginx from my localhost(working) ->I went to the container terminal->I clone the DVWA from github to /usr/share/nginx/html/DVWA directory (all the DVWA files are there)-> I went to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf to edit the nginx configuration file-> I have configured everything and checked the version of my php to be compatible-> I checked the log found /run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock not a file or directory (I fixed the issue)-> now when checking the log (/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock   permission denied)/ I  ensured all the permissions are correct. However, still permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I was just recently able to deploy DVWA using nginx. It took some fiddling around with the PHP part of DVWA, but in general, it works. Everything is packed into a single Docker container too.

If interested, you can have a look here: https://github.com/seppzer0/nDVWA